# Log applications that use the camera on Android

Tags: android, camera

I am looking for an Android application that can find out which application if any uses the camera.

If possible:

- free
- can log applications that use the camera with start time and end time

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with a rooted Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Did you take a look at *LBE Security Master*? I'm using its pre-decessor ("LBE privacy guard"), which no longer works with 4.1 and up. You can have it logging all kind of access – not sure whether camera belongs to it with LSM. As the Playstore only has the Chinese version, you might wish to check out [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1422479), where they provide localized versions.